# Using the "IN" operator with a large list

Tags: mysql

I have a list of email addresses that I would like to use the "IN" operator in order to search for email addresses that match:

```
SELECT *
FROM Signups
WHERE emailID IN ()
```

I'd like to put a large list of emails from a .csv in here. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is very long, then I strongly advise you against using `IN`.

AFAIK there's no way to read the values of a CSV and using those values in a query.
You should import the data in a table, index it, and then join your table with the values you've just imported.

Example:

```
create table tbl_emails(
    id int unisgned not null auto_increment primary key,
    email varchar(100),
    index idx_email(email)
);
-- I'm assuming your file has only one column. If it has more columns, 
-- include them in your table.
load data infile 'path/to/your/file.csv'
into table tbl_emails
fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
-- ignore 1 lines -- If your file has a header, uncomment this line
(email) -- If your file has lesser columns than the table, you must include the 
        -- column list here: (field1, field2, ....)
;
select a.*
from signups as a
     inner join tbl_emails as b on a.emailId = b.email;
```

If you really want to use `in`, then:

```
select *
from signups
where emailId in (select email from tbl_emails);
```

[Read the documentation for `load data`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need this query once, you can open the CSV in Excel or Notepad++ and run a macro to concat all the addresses together with commas inbetween.

For a more structural solution, you can import the CSV in MySQL itself, and use that table in the `in` list:

```
SELECT *
FROM Signups
WHERE emailID IN (SELECT EMAIL from CSVImportTable)
```